# how to read a line with indefinite entries into a numerical array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been struggling with it a whole day and think it is time for me to seek some help. The data file is the following

```
num - eFERMI:
    -0.062062        0.061938       -0.000220       -0.064446        0.064839
```

I need to identify the line with eFERMI and then read in the next line into a numerical array whose entries need to be determined when read in the data.

The code I came up with is something like the following

```
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <math.h>

 using namespace std;

 int main(){

   int nx=5;
   double *dE_fdx=new double [nx];

   FILE *f1;
   char buf[1000];  string sbuf;
   char* pch,*rsr;

   f1=fopen("deriv_num.dat","r");

   // try find out the line with eFERMI
   do{ fgets(buf,1000,f1); sbuf=string(buf); }while(sbuf.find("eFERMI")==std::string::npos);

   // if successfully found, then read in the coming line
   if(sbuf.find("eFERMI")!=std::string::npos){
     fgets(buf,1000,f1);  rsr=buf;
     int i=0;
     while((pch=strtok_r(rsr," ",&rsr))){
       if(i>=nx){ cout << "i>=nx\n"; exit(1);}
       dE_fdx[i++]=atof(pch);
     }
   }
   else
     exit(1);

   fclose(f1);

 }
```

The execution seems to take the trailing white space to be zeros, which is not what I expect and I don't know how to get rid of the trailing white space for a character pointer. Also, I am not familiar with character treatment with c/c++, thus the code must need improving in its elegency if not its full validity. I would be really appreciated if one could rewrite it in a professional way.

Comment: I see you are using C++.  Rather than trying to work with a fixed size array, or allocate an array on-the-fly, consider using std::vector.

Comment: why are you not going to use `vector` instead of `array` ?

Comment: Use iostreams and not the C-FILE API.

Comment: There doesn't exist a language named C/C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you shouldn't use pure char arrays because they are more error-prone and harded to maintain then `std::string`. Also [c](/questions/tagged/c) file API is replaced with `fstream`.

Here is example how it could be done in C++ using

- [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)
- [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)
- [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)
- [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

**Output:** -0.062062 0.061938 -0.00022 -0.064446 0.064839

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("deriv_num.dat");
    std::string line;
    std::vector<double> nums;
    double temp;

    while (std::getline(f, line))
    {
        if (line.find("eFERMI") != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::getline(f, line);
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            while (ss >> temp)
            {
                nums.push_back(temp);
            }
        }
    }

    for (double& it : nums)
    {
        std::cout << it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```